# how to use XPath to find the node value with CDATA tag in java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I used XPath to parse rss xml data, and the data is

```
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>
      <![CDATA[sports news]]>
    </title>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

I want to get the text "sports news" using xpath "/rss/channel/title/text()" ,but the result is not what I want ,the real result is "\r\n",so how to found the result I want.

the code is below:

```
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);
    XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xPath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
    Node node = (Node) xPath.evaluate("/rss/channel/title/text()", doc,XPathConstants.NODE);
    String title = node.getNodeValue();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try calling [setCoalescing(true)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setCoalescing%28boolean%29) on your DocumentBuilderFactory and this will collapse all CDATA/text nodes into single nodes.

Comment: or pass XPathConstants.NODESET, and assign evaluate to a NodeList. But coalescing is the easier thing to do.

Comment: Officially, in the XPath data model, text nodes are never split into pieces, so your query should return the result you expect. In practice, some XPath implementations that work on a DOM will fail to concatenate adjacent text nodes. One solution is to avoid use of text() (use string() on the element instead); another is to use setCoalescing() as suggested; a third is to use a conformant XPath processor, such as Saxon.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the XPath expression to

```
"string(/rss/channel/title)"
```

and use return type STRING instead of NODE:

```
Node node = (Node) xPath.evaluate("string(/rss/channel/title)", doc,
                                  XPathConstants.STRING);
```

This way you are not selecting a text node, but rather the string value of the title element, which consists of the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes.