# How to skip <![CDATA[ ]]> in java when processing XMLTree?

Tags: java, xml, rss, cdata

I'm writing code for class (Software I) to process an XMLtree of RSS feeds and output into html. We were provided an example of an [XMLInput](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/software/2221/web-sw1/assignments/projects/rss-aggregator/feeds.xml) file.

Specifically, I'm having trouble with [this feed](https://rss.packetstormsecurity.com/news/) and the description tag that has the CDATA in it.

I've read every post on StackOverflow with the CDATA tag and haven't found one that makes sense to me/is not written with document builder/factory etc.

My code snippet where I keep getting an error with the CDATA tag is below.

```
if (item.child(i).label().contentEquals("description")) {
                description = item.child(i).child(0).toString();

                if (description.indexOf('<') != -1) {
                    description = description.substring(0,
                            description.indexOf('<'));

                }
```

Expected results are an html table with pubDate, Source, and Description with link. Such as the provided [sample output](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/software/2221/web-sw1/assignments/projects/rss-aggregator/packetstorm.html). This sample is for the feed I linked above.

Actual results:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Violation of: k < the number of subtrees of the root of this
    at components.xmltree.XMLTree1.child(Unknown Source)

The error ties to the .toString() line in the code snippet above and only triggers with the rss linked above.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it and using the J! button in the Breakpoints view to stop when the error is thrown?

Comment: Take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553697/reading-cdata-xml-in-java/11562084